# How to use the SymbolName of variables along with Map and pure function

Tags: graphics3d, labeling, hold, symbols

I want to label each point of a `Graphics3D` with the simplest method as possible.

I tried many solutions like this :

```
 Manipulate[
  α ∈ Reals; A1 = {-1, 0, 1}; A2 = {Cos[α], Sin[2 α], -2};
  With[{polyw = PolyhedronData[poly, "Polyhedron"]}, 
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], 
    Map[{Text[Style[SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]]], RGBColor[Abs[#] // Round], 1.1 #], 
       Style[Point[#], RGBColor[Abs[Round[#]]]]} &, {A1, A2, B1, B2}],         
    MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, PolyhedronCoordinates[polyw]], 
    polyw}]], 
  {α, 0, Pi}, {poly, "Cube"}
]
```

But the variable `#` is evalute before the function `Unevaluate`

So I would like to know if there are a simple method to print the name of the variable  (I have many, many points to enable in the graphic).

Maybe by using `Information[]` ?

Comment: As an aside, your first line inside the Manipulate `Element[alpha, Reals]` does nothing for you. You should include it in the global `$Assumptions` or wrap thinks in `Assuming`, or use the `Assumptions ->` option for functions that have it.

Comment: `B1`, `B2` are not defined in your code. You also have an odd `Style[SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]]]` within your `Text`: that's a call to `Style` without any styling directives, so it won't do much for you. More in general, can you simplify your code to a MUCH simpler minimal working example that gives rise to the same problem? For instance, what features do you want to label, and which labels do you want to use for each feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter values as strings and convert to expressions.

**EDIT:** Added [`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) control

```
Manipulate[
 A1 = {-1, 0, 1};
 A2 = {Cos[α], Sin[2 α], -2};
 With[
  {polyw = PolyhedronData[poly, "Polyhedron"]},
  Graphics3D[{
    PointSize[0.03],
    Map[{
       RGBColor @@ Abs[#[[2]] // Round],
       Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], {1.5, 1.5}],
       Point[#[[2]]]} &,
     Thread[{#, ToExpression@#}] &@{"A1", "A2"}],
    MapIndexed[
     Text[#2[[1]], #] &,
     PolyhedronCoordinates[polyw]],
    {Opacity[opac], polyw}}]],
 {{α, 1.}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{opac, 0.5, "Opacity"}, 0, 1, 0.05,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{poly, "Cube", Polyhedron},
  PolyhedronData["Platonic"],
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Bob for your answer.     **But** I am very surprise that an software as efficient and developed as this does not have a very simple method for doing an very very simple action and very useful !!!    Could someone tell me why Wolfram does not apparently want to include such a method in the build  ?